# What is the quickest way to kill everybody?

Tags: plague-inc

After a bit of practice I am now easily getting to a point where my plague infects the entire planet.

[image]

I am finding that with symptoms like Total Organ Failure and Comas that my plagues have a medium level of lethality and while everybody seems to die off pretty quickly I was wondering if these two are in fact the quickest way of killing everybody off.

So, now that everybody is infected with my plague - what is the quickest way to kill everybody off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All the big 30-point symptoms near the center line are excellent at killing people off in job lots, although tricks like Pneumonia or Hypersensitivity can potentially be more effective in their specialized areas (As the descriptions state, Pneumonia is especially dangerous in cold areas while hypersensitivity is particularly dangerous in urban environments where exposure to various allergens is much more common).

I'm personally a fan of Coma because it also makes the disease harder to cure and Necrosis because it means that corpses still remain infective (which can be a big plus if you haven't infected everyone yet).

Comment: I'm not just suggesting it, I'm outright *stating* it. Have a disease with cure about 30% complete, develop 'Coma' and watch as completion drops to 26% or so, depending on other factors.

Comment: Interesting, because I normally have around 100 DNA points to spend when I'm ready to go lethal I just normally add a load of symptoms at once and thus my cure % is at 0 when I add stuff like coma, I guess this is how I missed that. Do all of the methods of death kill at the same rate do you know?

Comment: Not sure, honestly. I suppose the only way to test it is to study the post-genocide graphs of near-identical diseases with just one symptom swapped in or out. Feel like killing all of humanity off a few dozen times for science?

Comment: I think working your way up to internal hemorraging deserves an honerable mention since it always puts me over the edge when I have total organ failure. Also, if you ever get tight on DNA, you can always sell your infectious abilities to purchase deadlier symptoms.

Comment: Once everyone is infected, I always (except in the rare cases where devolving actually costs DNA points) devolve all of my transmission points so I can maximize the symptoms. There's no reason to transmit the disease if everyone already has it. :)

Answer (score 8):

I personally usually go with these two in the middle here:

[image]

The two abilities are:

- Total Organ Failure
- Coma

I'm not sure if these are the *fastest* ways to kill off a population but between them they'll usually result in a world population graph that looks like this (assuming the whole population was infected before you went lethal):

[image]

Comment: I tend to avoid TAF in general because the path *to* it tends to contain highly-visible diseases and I love infecting every single country on the planet before people even realize there's a new disease on the block...

Comment: Yeah but i infect everybody before turning lethal as per the screenshot on my question showing all infected and none dead

Comment: Ah, so you avoid the entire tree and just save up to strike a single blow? That works.

Comment: @kalina I found just pumping everything into transmission and cold/drug resistance the most effective way for viruses, saving the devolving for a few key traits that makes them much more visible. (And evolve necrosis to make it spread even while killing of the population.) The virus should infect and kill fast enough with this tactic to reach all areas and holding up research by killing off everyone.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good method:

1. **Wait until everybody is infected** (a message will pop up saying "There are no healthy people left").
2. If you use a Bio-weapon, go to step 11,if not, go to the next step.
3. **Evolve** Coughing, Sneezing, Pulmonary Fibrosis and **Total Organ Failure** - this is your main symptom (you can devolve Coughing, Sneezing and Pulmonary Fibrosis for extra DNA points).
4. If cure progress is over 80%, go to step 6, else go to step 5.
5. You don't need to worry about the cure. Instead, **evolve better symptoms**:

   - Hemorrhagic Shock - very lethal (evolve Anaemia, Haemophilia and  Internal Haemorrhaging)
   - Necrosis - very lethal (After Hemorrhagic Shock)
   - Tumours - doesn't increase severity, but is lethal (after Haemophilia)
   - Internal Haemorrhaging - quite lethal (after Haemophilia)
   - Systemic infection - quite lethal (after Tumours)
   - Immune Suppression - quite lethal (after Sneezing)
   - Dysentery - quite lethal (after Diarrhoea)
6. Get **Insomnia and Paranoia** (slows research).
7. Get **Seizures** (after Paranoia) and **Insanity** (after Seizures) - reverses cure efforts. Devolve Seizures if you want.
8. Get **Coma and Paralysis** - slightly lethal and reverses cure (after Total Organ Failure).
9. If the cure still builds up get **Genetic Reshuffle** in the Abilities section.
10. Get some of the good symptoms from step 5.
11. Get the **Annihalation Genes** (In Abilities) - Completely fills the Lethality bar (after all 3 of its main abilities).
12. **Watch the world die!**

Answer (score 1):

I just play with transmission, not symptoms, until everyone is infected, then evolve Anaemia, Haemophillia, Internal Haemorrhaging and the next one up. Costs around 70-80 points altogether

Answer (score 1):

I usually start with something like coughing and sneezing. After like 80% of the world is infected, evolve immune suppresion and when 90% is infected total organ failure and coma. Now, you see how the world is doing. Cure is going too fast? Coma>Paralysis>inflammation>Paranoia(Can also pick up insomnia as well)>Seizures>Insanity. Need more lethality? Coma>Systemic infection>Tumors>Internal hammeorging> Hemmrotic shock> Necrosis.    If everybody is dying too quickly, Immune suppresion>Fever>skin lesions>Necrosis.    When the pop-up that says(THERE ARE NO HEALTHY PEOPLE LEFT IN THE WORLD)appears, coughing and sneezing can be devolved for extra dna points.

Answer (score 0):

With no bonus genes, using bacteria..not that that matters I think, starting in India on Brutal.

- Water 1
- Air 1
- Drug Resist 1
- Water 2
- Air 2
- (Whatever the air and water combo is)
- Cold resist 1
- Drug resist 2
- Cold resist 2
- Hardening 1

Devolve mutated symptoms until everyone is infected. You should not have to pay for any of the downgrades.

Once everyone is infected, devolve two skills in transmissions, and the two cold resists from the abilities tab.

Go to your symptoms and starting with the bottom left one, go straight diagonally to the right and go up one...ends with total organ failure and then I added my left overs into seizures.

You shouldn't have any issues. Watch your points, and just pump them into going to the right, so you can get the internal hemorrhaging, tumors, etc. I also added the dysentery, first, before I went right.

Comment: Could you perhaps source reference to the abilities, instead of referencing the direction or position they are placed on the skill tree? This can come across as confusing, for some.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, I just saw a post which took 24,000 days to end the game.
I'm not sure if that was mega brutal or a difficult pathogen, but anyway, this is how my world graph on normal - virus looks like -
[image]

Ok, so the best way I use to end the population is by-

1. Wait until the people are fully infected.
2. If this is the normal or casual mode, devolve the infection traits and the cold resistance or heat etc. Be careful to not devolve the drug resistance or spl. abilities.
   Doing this may give you DNA points, but just in case check the are you sure tab that does it give you DNA points or you have to spend them.
3. Wait till the DNA points reach max, or till 60-80 points and then start evolving the coughing symptom tree till total organ failure. After mass deaths happen, and the cure research is speeding up, you get DNA points for mass deaths , and that's a lot of it.
4. Evolve insomnia to insanity, and then wait for the deaths to happen and listen to the music... If the cure is slow, you may try coma too.

Once I got stuck and was lacking DNA points, and cure was fast up. I quickly evolved the insomnia symptom tree and then accumulated DNA points to get mass deaths only with insanity.